ACF Google Map - Get marker IDs to interact with external div
I am using the setup from this page:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/google-map/
This is creating a Google map with two markers on it correctly. However, rather than simply an infowindow for each marker, I need to be able to toggle show/hide external div containers which sits outside of my map. I've searched everywhere but cannot work out how to do this.
Even if I add a custom field of marker ID to the object, I can't seem to manipulate this in the code. Can anyone help?
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open( map, marker );
        
    });


Can anyone help with this?
